# Set Configurable Product Price for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

we migrated from magento 1 to magento 2.

and now we are having problems on configurable product price because magento 2 no longer allow a price on the parent product. the thing is we have more than 10 stores and the price was set differently on those stores. so now, when we add a new configuration(simple product) on a configurable. we need to generate the simple product first then edit the simple product for all store views.

all i need is to retain a price for the parent product so that when a configuration is created, it will just copy price of the parent product for all store views. like in magento 1. any idea on how we can make this work?

Comment: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-magento-2-configurable-product-price.html this may help you

Comment: @ArunKumar i already checked that one. maybe its outdated. because configurable products no longer work as it was described in there. im using 2.4.0. and when you create a configuration on a configurable product. it will remove the price then the parent parent product wont be having a price after saving it

Comment: Sadly, that is undoable without an extension.